# Find eigenvectors with specific eigenvalue of sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a large sparse matrix and I want to find its eigenvectors with specific eigenvalue. In scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs, it says the required argument k:

"k is the number of eigenvalues and eigenvectors desired. k must be smaller than N-1. It is not possible to compute all eigenvectors of a matrix".

The problem is that I don't know how many eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue I want. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Is your matrix a banded matrix?

Comment: @gboffi I used Block sparse row matrix

Comment: Inverse iteration with shifts is, in general, the way to go to find a single eigenvalue. Details depend on the structure of the matrix and the nature of the eigenvalues, that we ignore, Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration#Theory_and_convergence and this, that applies to optimizations possible when  your matrix is symmetric and banded, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration#Tridiagonalization.2C_Hessenberg_form

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) instead. There is a function from `scipy` where you can use SVD `from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds` and it can handle sparse matrix. You can find eigenvalues (in this case will be singular value) and eigenvectors by the following:

```
U, Sigma, VT = svds(X, k=n_components, tol=tol)
```

where `X` can be sparse CSR matrix, `U` and `VT` is set of left eigenvectors and  right eigenvectors corresponded to singular values in `Sigma`. Here, you can control number of components. I'd say start with small `n_components` first and then increase it. You can rank your `Sigma` and see the distribution of singular value you have. There will be some large number and drop quickly. You can make threshold on how many eigenvectors you want to keep from singular values.

If you want to use `scikit-learn`, there is a class `sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD` that let you do what I explained.

Comment: For SVD, the singular value are the absolute values of eigenvalues, but my eigenvalues might contain 1 and -1. Also, I have to select those eigenvectors with specific eigenvalues with different size sparse matrix hundreds of times, so I don't think it is a good way for me to do it.

Comment: Ah, got it. Seems like a bit harder problem. I have to take a look later on.